# Get column names (headers) from hdf file

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I was wondering how to get the column names (seemingly stored in the hdf header) of an hdf file; for example, a file might have columns named [a,b,c,d] while another file has columns [a,b,c] and yet another has columns [b,e,r,z]; and I would like to find out which ones have which. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know about hdfstore, but what you call "column" probably is, in HDF5 terminology, a member of a compound datatype. Unfortunately, it seems that hdfstore doesn't seems to have the ability to inspect datatypes. With h5py you can: http://api.h5py.org/h5t.html#h5py.h5t.TypeCompoundID

Answer (score 7):

To do this outside of python you can use [h5dump](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Dump) via something like `h5dump --header my.hdf5`

In python you can use [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/2.3/)

As an example this is how I might access field names for my HDF-EOS5 file:

```
>>> import h5py
>>> f = h5py.File('/tmp/temp.hdf','r')
>>> f.keys()
[u'HDFEOS', u'HDFEOS INFORMATION']
>>> f.values()
[<HDF5 group "/HDFEOS" (2 members)>, <HDF5 group "/HDFEOS INFORMATION" (2 members)>]
>>> grpname = f.require_group('/HDFEOS')
>>> grpname.keys()
[u'ADDITIONAL', u'GRIDS']
>>> grpname.values()
[<HDF5 group "/HDFEOS/ADDITIONAL" (1 members)>, <HDF5 group "/HDFEOS/GRIDS" (9 members)>]
>>> subgrpname = grpname.require_group('/HDFEOS/GRIDS')
>>> subgrpname.keys()
[u'355nm_band', u'380nm_band', u'445nm_band', u'470nm_band', u'555nm_band', u'660nm_band', u'865nm_band', u'935nm_band', u'Ancillary']
>>> group_660 = subgrpname.require_group('660nm_band')
>>> group_660.keys()
[u'Data Fields']
>>> group_660.values()
[<HDF5 group "/HDFEOS/GRIDS/660nm_band/Data Fields" (20 members)>]
>>> fields_660 = group_660.require_group('Data Fields')
>>> fields_660.keys()
[u'AOLP_meridian', u'AOLP_scatter', u'DOLP', u'Glint_angle', u'I', u'I.mask', u'IPOL', u'Q.mask', u'Q_meridian', u'Q_scatter', u'RDQI', u'Scattering_angle', u'Sun_azimuth', u'Sun_zenith', u'Time_in_seconds_from_epoch', u'U.mask', u'U_meridian', u'U_scatter', u'View_azimuth', u'View_zenith']
>>> fields_660.values()
[<HDF5 dataset "AOLP_meridian": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "AOLP_scatter": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "DOLP": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "Glint_angle": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "I": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "I.mask": shape (3072, 3072), type "<i4">, <HDF5 dataset "IPOL": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "Q.mask": shape (3072, 3072), type "<i4">, <HDF5 dataset "Q_meridian": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "Q_scatter": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "RDQI": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "Scattering_angle": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "Sun_azimuth": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "Sun_zenith": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "Time_in_seconds_from_epoch": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f8">, <HDF5 dataset "U.mask": shape (3072, 3072), type "<i4">, <HDF5 dataset "U_meridian": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "U_scatter": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "View_azimuth": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">, <HDF5 dataset "View_zenith": shape (3072, 3072), type "<f4">]
```

Comment: Aren't these names of the DataSets rather than the column names within the DataSet?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. These are the names of the datasets. While I called them fields, I didn't mean columns of a vdata if that's what you mean, but data fields which contain data values. As an example, all 3072 columns of the AOLP_meridian "field" are just numeric indexes. The data I was using above uses a data value at a particular row and column to represent the value of that dataset at that physical location.

Comment: I see. I was confused.  We use the 'tables' module (pytables).  I mention that here in case it helps someone someday.  I was trying to access files created with tables using h5py, which caused me trouble.

Comment: What to do if keys() returns "/", while there are really names for the "tables"? I found this in a coursera dataset, the helper functions calls for table names, but using keys/values returns nothing. This is strange...?

Comment: Do you get anything in values()? I believe keys might be empty is there aren't any groups...

Comment: Actually it might have been a bug in versions or an error in my code. I updated my system and it now works fine. Thanks

Comment: same as I,my h5 file don't have group,it can't access the columns name